# Creating all possible sublists of an int list that sum up to a given limit

Tags: python-2.7

I'll try to explain as best as a can.

```
lst = [7.1, 6.3, 5.6, 3.7].
```

I want all the different combinations that fit inside 50 without shooting over it.

```
lst1 = [7.1, 7.1, 7.1, 7.1, 7.1, 7.1, 7.1]
print sum(lst1)
```

would give `49.7`.
Lists like `lst2 =[7.1,7.1,7.1 5.6, 5.6, 5.6, 3.7, 3.7, 3.7]` have to be there also. 
All the different combinations have to get into lists that will be checked for their sum to get as close to the target range as possible. I really don't know how to put it else and I wasn't able to find something similar to that. 
In short

1. How do I iterate through those numbers?
2. How do I add those numbers to lists?
3. How do I find the best combinations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the itertools library for your problem:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement as cwr
l1 = [1,2,3,4]
l2 = []

for i in range(0, 20):
    for j in list(cwr(l1,i)):
        if sum(j) < 20:
            l2.append(j)
print l2
```

Comment: Thank you for bringing itertools to my attention. I am not very acquainted with all the librarys available for python. With your help I made some changes and i have now the combinations and i can put them all into separate lists for further use.

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement as cwr  
l1 = [7.1,6.3,5.6]  
num = 0  
l2 = []  
l3 = []

for i in range(0, 20):  
    for j in list(cwr(l1,i)):  
        if 19 < sum(j) < 20:  
            l2.append(j)  
        elif 18 < sum(j) < 19:  
            l3.append(j)  
        else:  
            pass  

for i in range(len(l2)):
    lst = "List_" + str(num)
    num += 1
    lst = []
    lst.append(l2.pop())
    lst.sort()
    lst.reverse()
    print lst
```

Are there any tips you can give me for my solution?